# Why am I loosing permissions/ownership on old windows folders?

Tags: windows, permissions

So each time I format my computer to reinstall windows (malware infestation or motherboard change) I usually make a backup of my C drive, put it in the “BCK” folder and then forget it

I’ve been doing that that since I was 12 (I’m 33 today), at first I was using windows 95, now windows 10 and those are basically time capsules (I have a lot of space , when I run out of spaces I purchase bigger HDDs instead of deleting stuff)

I’ve been digging into them today, and when trying to access some folders I get this permission problem

**My question is : Why does this happens? This is not the first time that I get this, it happens randomly on old folders.**

Each time I format I change my computer name and user name, but this does not causes this problem, this problem appears years after leaving and old folder alone. Why?

it is not a windows 10 issue, it also happened on windows 7, and windows xp if I remember correctly (I used those versions 95->98->vista->xp->7->10)

*To illustrate here is what I had to do to be able to access the files in the folder “DISQUE C 899” and the files in its subfolders :*

[image]

After clicking “Continue” :

[image]

After clicking on security tab and messing around :

[image]

Then it change to that :

[image]

So I checked “Replace owner on subcontainers and objects” and hitted apply (because It seems to be what I want)

[image]

So I cliqued “yes”

[image]

Allright

So now, I’m browsing the inside of the folder, Nice!

[image]

But I can’t look at pictures :

[image]

Ok so modifying the permissions of each files is going to make me crazy, I remembered that I could do it on the root folder so I’m going to try to do it on “DISQUE C 899” maybe it will apply it on every files/subfolders of the main folder

[image]

Looks like I just have to check one button

[image]

Yes please.

Success, now I can look at pictures that I saved 13 years ago! :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Each time I format I change my computer name and user name, but this does not causes this problem, this problem appears years after leaving and old folder alone. Why?

You may or may not change your user name, but there is something that changes every time: The [Security Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier) (SID) of the account, which also happens to be the key used to store permissions in NTFS.

A SID looks like this:

> S-1-5-21-3623811015-3361044348-30300820-1013

To not get these problems, set inheritable permissions on external drives. Allow “Everyone” full access. “Everyone” is a built-in identity that is the same on every Windows installation. By default, new files and folders (and also regularly copied stuff) will inherit these permissions.

This problem is not random at all. But maybe you already have universally valid permissions on some of your hard drives.

Comment: The problem also wouldn't exist on FAT/exFAT drives (which don't store ownership or permissions), but on the downside, those might not be as reliable as NTFS due to lack of journalling...

Comment: thanks, I must be  wrong, i was under the impression that some copied folder were accessible and then one day became locked, maybe they were locked since the beginning and I never opened them, I'll put "Everyone" for all of them